# .ipa file stuck on installing on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes, ipa

I seen some answers in google but am not getting proper solution.I am trying to install my ipa file in my iphone but it's stuck on INSTALLING.

Am using Xcode 6.1.1 with iOS 8.1
My iphone is 8.1.2 version

My questions are ?
1. Which profile can i use for deploy ipa file into real device Development or distribution.
2. It is necessary to add real device in to member center for installing ipa file.
3. Before click on archive how can i fill my Xcode Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Which profile can I use for deploy ipa file into real device Development or distribution.

===> both devlopment and distribution could use for deploy ipa file

> 2. It is necessary to add real device in to member center for installing ipa file.

===> yes. you must add device udid to profile devices list. follow this [link](http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-teach/how-to-prepare/ios-device-provisioning.html) to see how to config provisioning profile

> 3. Before click on archive how can i fill my Xcode Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile fields.

==> you could follow this [link](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1333914-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-5-) to archive

or you could follow [App Distribution Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: Thanks for replay one more question is it not possible to install my app in to other unknown device.

Comment: it's possible but you must have enterprise distribution: http://johannesluderschmidt.de/provision-ios-ipa-app-for-in-house-enterprise-distribution/2993/

Comment: is it not possible with 99$ developer account ?

Comment: yes, with 99$ account you must add device to provision profile devices list

Comment: one more thing... can i save in app store with 99$ developer account ?

Comment: sorry, I can't get you ?

Comment: Can i upload my app in APP STORE with 99$ developer account ?

Comment: certainly, yes you can:)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install IPA file on IOS.

1. Download (https://pangu8.com/sideloadly) Sideloadly.
2. Now connect your iphone to your PC.
3. After connecting your iphone to your pc the iDevice should be auto detected.
4. Now enter your apple account and select IPA by brosing to your pc.
5. Click on start button.
6. Enter your apple account password.
7. You should see the app install in your iphone.
8. If you see untrusted developer error then go to setting of your phone.
9. Select device management and click on trust developer.